# How to use flatMap with Subject in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, subscribe, flatmap, subject

I have a problem with `Subject`

```
this.subjectService.createNext(this.service.getData(pageNumber=1)
this.subjectService.createNext(this.service.getData(pageNumber=2)
this.subjectService.createNext(this.service.getData(pageNumber=3)
```

I call 3 next methods because I have to download three API pages with data (3x10).

In another component I subscribe this subject:

```
this.subjectService.getData()
  .pipe(flatMap(res => res))
  .subscribe((result) => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

I'm using flatMap because without flatMap i receive:

```
>> Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
>> Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
>> Observable {_isScalar: false, source: Observable, operator: MapOperator}
```

The problem is that when I'm using flatMap then I can't iterate all pageNumbers.

```
this.subjectService.getData()
.pipe(tap(() =>
console.log(pageNumber))) /* It returns 1,2,3

.pipe(flatMap(res => res))

.pipe(tap(() =>
console.log(pageNumber))) /* after flatMap: It returns 3,3,3

.subscribe((result) => {
console.log(result);
      });
```

Maybe you know how to mix flatMap (to get normal data, avoid _isScalar...) and iterate all pageNumbers per observable, not only last called with createNext(pageNumber=3).

Comment: What is createNext?

Comment: createNext is the function placed in subject.service.ts . This function includes code: this.subject.next(apiCall, pageNumber);

Comment: This looks more complicated then it should be. Why not just use a combineLatest with 3 http calls? Or a merge? Or forkJoin? Why the additional Subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should attach your page number with the observable you created from `this.service.getData`.

Like this

```
this.subjectService
  .createNext(
    this.service.getData(1)
      .pipe(map(data => ({ data, pageNumber: 1 }))
  )

this.subjectService
  .createNext(
    this.service.getData(2)
      .pipe(map(data => ({ data, pageNumber: 2 }))
  )

this.subjectService
  .createNext(
    this.service.getData(3)
      .pipe(map(data => ({ data, pageNumber: 3 }))
  )
```

The data you receive with the flatmap will be

```
// { data: { some: 'object' }, pageNumber: 1 }
// { data: { some: 'object' }, pageNumber: 2 }
// { data: { some: 'object' }, pageNumber: 3 }
```